# How to get the boot partition in a Batch file?

Tags: windows, batch

Although usually people install Windows in partition `C`,I think there'll be some problems if I just use `C:\\` as the boot directory.I've googled this but did not find the key. So how can I get the boot partition in Batch?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're asking for the _boot_ volume's drive letter, not the [system volume's](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html).  The _windows directory_ and the _system directory_ (usually) live on the _boot_ volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the System Variable `%SystemDrive%` to change to the Windows Directory. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#System_path_variables) has a good list of system variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%SystemDrive%` environment variable.

It will (for example) return `C:`, so remember to add the directory divider after it manually.